# Shortcuts not working right

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

All my shortcuts on Desktop and in the Start Menu open the same program instead of what they were supposed to open. I don't know how I messed them up.

Comment: What program are they opening?

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft recently released a patch that has to do with shortcuts.  That may have broken them.

Answer (score 0):

[This registry entry](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-asso-fixes-for-windows-7/) will fix it for you. It has a list of the default file associations all saved in .REG format for all versions of Windows from XP and up. When a program goes in and messes up certain key elements (i.e. EXE, SCR, BAT, CMD, REG, etc), the only options are to replace the affected areas with a registry entry from a known working system that is running the same version of Windows as you, or re-installing from scratch. This page is a favourite in my cell phone, as I can always download the patch I need whereever I am for my customers.

What this page does is give you a .REG file to run, which should default to adding the information back to the registry to restore the default command for whatever filetype you are looking for; in this isntance, look for the .LNK fix